# Is a function Riemann integrate iff the pullback of Jordan sets are Jordan?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I know that a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable iff for every Lebesgue measurable set $A \subset \mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Can a similar thing be said for Riemann integrable functions, ie, $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if for every Jordan measurable set $A \subset \mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is Jordan measurable? If not can any similiar statement be recovered?

Thanks.

Comment: The first statement is false: there are  continuous functions $f$ such that $f^{-1}(A)$ is nonmeasurable for some $A$ that is Lebesgue measurable. What you want is $A$ Borel measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! As it stands this is not true. Take for instance the function $f(x) = |x|$. It is not "integrable" in that the the Riemann sums diverge on $\mathbb{R}$, but it satisfies your assumptions.

Adding the assumption that the domain and codomain are bounded closed intervals of the real line, a function $f: [a, b] \to [c, d]$ for which $f^{-1}(A)$ is Jordan measurable for every Jordan measurable set $A\subset [c, d]$, seems to me to be Riemann integrable. To see this, partition $[a, b]$ into intervals $\{I_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of length $\frac{\epsilon}{n(b-a)}$, then, with $J_i = f^{-1}(I_i)$, the the upper and lower Riemann/Darboux sums read
$$\left| \sum_{i=1}^n M_i l(J_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n m_i l(J_i) \right| = \left| \sum_{i=1}^n (M_i - m_i) l(J_i) \right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\epsilon}{n(b-a)}l(J_i) = \epsilon$$

But unfortunately, even with these added assumption, the converse is still not true. That is, even if $f:[a, b]\to [c, d]$ is continuous (hence Riemann integrable), there is no reason the preimage of a Jordan measurable set should be Jordan measurable, as can be seen in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462292/preimages-of-jordan-measurable-sets/462463) post.

Comment: Thanks for your help!